# Duvida em sql, join entre tabelas e resultados

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo um join entre tabelas, onde preciso retornar todas as linhas da primeira tabela, no entanto eu uso um where para limitar no campo da data, sendo assim, acaba limitando o meu resultado a somente as linhas que pertence a aquela data especifica, fazendo assim com que n retorne todas as linhas da primeira tabela. No caso, todas as linhas da primeira tabela que não estiverem nessa data, devem retornar 0, alguém me da uma luz de como fazer ?

obs: já estou usando left outer join pra pegar todos os dados da primeira tabela.

```
select aa.nome_do_curso, count(cc.alunos_matriculados) contagem

from curso aa

        left outer join id_aluno bb on aa.curso_ident = bb.curso_ident
        left outer join matricula cc on bb.curso_registro = cc.curso_registro
        left outer join periodo dd on cc.periodo_a = dd.periodo_a

where dd.data like '2006' or dd.data like '2007'                                                    

group by  aa.nome_do_curso
order by 'contagem' desc
```

onde data = varchar

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta e colocar a sua query?

Comment: Compartilha a Query que você tem. Só editar e adicionar.

Comment: Você está pegando todos os valores da segunda tabela ao fazer `right join`

Comment: Para exibir a linha tem que usar uma subquery ao invés de um where

Comment: Acredito que a pergunta esteja duplicada, talvez essa resposta ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Comment: Mano, altera a sua questão e posta os códigos da sua query

Comment: alterei, ficou meio bugado ai na hora de postar, mas espero que entendam :[

Comment: `data` vem de qual tabela?

Comment: data vem da tabela periodo

Comment: (Primeiro que seu SQL não roda) E `alunos_matriculados` já não é a soma da quantidade de alunos do curso? Ou de qual tabela pertence esse campo?

Comment: Ta um pouco estranha a sua consulta. Você quer o total de alunos matriculados em cada curso nos anos de 2006 e 2007?

Comment: alunos_matriculados vem de qual tabela? seria legal colocar os prefixos nos campos do select, para nosso entendimento e também para suas manutenções futuras. Seu campo data é texto mesmo? (char ou varchar ou algo do tipo)

Comment: Isso Emanuel, quero os alunos matriculados em 2006 e 2007 e se tiver um curso que não tenha aluno, que retorne 0 na pesquisa que tou fazendo

Comment: @Mahatt já tentou utilizar apenas `left join`

Comment: @Mahatt tenta esse query: `SELECT aa.nome_do_curso, 
  dd.data,
       Count(cc.alunos_matriculados) AS contagem 
FROM   curso aa 
       LEFT JOIN id_aluno bb 
                    ON aa.curso_ident = bb.curso_ident 
       LEFT JOIN matricula cc 
                    ON bb.curso_registro = cc.curso_registro 
       LEFT JOIN periodo dd 
                    ON cc.periodo_a = dd.periodo_a 
WHERE  (dd.data LIKE '2006' OR dd.data LIKE '2007' )
GROUP  BY aa.nome_do_curso 
ORDER  BY contagem DESC `